# Create an empty Binary Tree in Python

Tags: python-3.x, binary-tree

I'm a beginner in programming, and I couldn't find the answer in other questions.
I'd like to create an empty binary tree of height h.

My code:

```
class node:
    def __init__(self, a = None):
        self.value = a
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

def postorder(tree,abba):
    if tree != None:
        postorder(tree.left,abba)
        postorder(tree.right,abba)
        abba.append(tree.value)

def inorder(tree,abba):
  if tree != None:
      inorder(tree.left,abba)
      abba.append(tree.value)
      inorder(tree.right,abba)
```

I would like to define a function

```
def getBinaryTree(h):
```

That gives me a tree with level h. So:
[empty tree of level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HcLm.gif)

Any ideas?

Comment: you can define a class for a binary tree. then keep adding nodes to the tree until the tree has a height of `h`.

Comment: @WasiAhmad How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**

To make a binary tree with height `h`, you need to add `2^(h+1)-1` nodes. A tree with height 0 means, the tree contains only one node and that is the root. For example, to create a tree with height 3, you need to add `2^(3+1)-1 = 15` nodes.

If you want to create a set of nodes which can form a binary tree with your given code, you can do something like this.

```
import math

class node:
    def __init__(self, a = None):
        self.value = a
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

def getBinaryTree(tree_height):
    tree_nodes = [None] * int((math.pow(2, tree_height+1) - 1))
    for i in range(tree_height):
        start_index = int(math.pow(2, i) - 1)
        end_index = int(math.pow(2, i+1) - 1)
        for j in range(start_index, end_index):
            tree_nodes[j] = node(j)
            if j == 0: continue
            if j % 2 == 0: # a right child
                parent_index = int((j - 2) / 2)
                tree_nodes[parent_index].right = tree_nodes[j]
            else: # a left child
                parent_index = int((j - 1) / 2)
                tree_nodes[parent_index].left = tree_nodes[j]

    return tree_nodes[0] # returns the root node

def printTree(tree_node, inorder_tree_walk):
    if tree_node != None:
        printTree(tree_node.left, print_tree)
        inorder_tree_walk.append(tree_node.value)
        printTree(tree_node.right, print_tree)

root = getBinaryTree(4)
inorder_tree_walk = []
printTree(root, inorder_tree_walk)
print(inorder_tree_walk)
```

> So, what the program does?

The program creates `2^(h+1)-1` nodes to form a tree with height `h`. Nodes are stored in list `tree_nodes`. Parent-child relationship between nodes are stored in `tree_nodes` as follows.

- Left child of element `i`: (2i + 1)th element
- Right child of element `i`: (2i + 2)th element

When a children node is created, it is set as a left/right children of its parent.

Comment: Yes I've seen this code before. But I don't know how to manipulate it in orde to create an empty tree of a certain height

Comment: @Whizkid95 empty tree means a tree with nodes having no value, right? to do that, you can put a dummy value in the nodes. and there you can compute how many nodes you required to create a tree with height `h`. So, you can keep adding that many nodes to make a binary tree with of height `h`.

Comment: I get the idea, but I don't know how to implement this in my code?